# XLL issue with xlfEvaluate

Tags: excel, xll

I have this problem with a very simple function written in an XLL, using VS2012. I have tried reading up in MSDN and Steve Dalton's book, and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.
The tricky bit is that I need my function to read values in worksheet cells other than the one from which it is called. The function takes no arguments, and returns an integer. I have declared it as J# (the # signifying that it can call XLM functionality as advised by Dalton...although I still get the same problem without the #). I have not included the declaration of my function to save space, but it is simple and I do not think it is the cause of the problem.

This first block of code works fine. I wrote it just to build confidence.

```
//This block works correctly. A trial copied from the old Excel 97 documentation
XLOPER12 xlInput1, xlOutput2;
/* Evaluate the string "2+3" */
xlInput1.xltype = xltypeStr;
xlInput1.val.str = L"\0032+3";  //prefix with string length in Octal
Excel12(xlfEvaluate, &xlOutput2, 1, (LPXLOPER12) &xlInput1); 
//works OK, and xlOutput2 contains 5
```

But this second block does not work. I cannot see why. I am trying to read a value from a cell, which is a different cell from that from which the function was called. What I get is an return XLOPER12 that contains an error (xltypeErr) and junk values in the val.num field (the worksheet cell does contain an integer value).

```
//This block does not work
XLOPER12 xlInput3, xlOutput3;
/* Look up the name Tst on the active sheet called Sht */
xlInput3.xltype = xltypeStr;
xlInput3.val.str = L"\003Tst";  //this also gives problems regardless of whether the string is defined as \004!Tst or \007Sht!Tst
Excel12(xlfEvaluate, &xlOutput3, 1, (LPXLOPER12) &xlInput3);  //xlOutput3 now has a type of xltypeErr, rather than the correct integer value on the worksheet
```

Can you kindly explain what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to read a value from a cell that is different from the cell calling the function you'll need a parameter to refer to that different cell. For example in A1 you may have '=myfunc(A2)'. Then your C++ extension func will need to be declared 'JP#', with the P corresponding to the A2 cell reference parameter. If Excel can resolve the 'A2' reference it will pass in an XLOPER with that value as xltypeNum, xltypeInt or xltypeStr depending on the the contents of A2. If not you may get an xltypeSRef.

xlfEvaluate: here's the MS doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687913(v=office.15).aspx

Note that MS specify that the string passed to xlfEvaluate must 'contain only functions, not command equivalents'. I suspect L"\003Tst" doesn't correspond to any function known to your Excel. There's no built in function called Tst in my Excel 2013. It's possible you have an addin that supplies a function called Tst, but I'm guessing not. So try changing xlInput3.val.str to L"\006RAND()" and see what happens.